# the SherlockActivity restart when change the orientation

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

I need help with the ActionBarSherlock when the orientation is changed the activity restart and disconnect all my services and the app crash i tried to add this lines to the file AdroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

and this lines in the activity file:

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
```

but don't work.

any suggestion ???

Thank you and regards.

P.D.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what is the logcat o/p when crash happens

Comment: is this your application for both orientations portrait and landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your manifest.xml add this line in your activity

```
 <activity android:name="Your Activity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```